# automatically open new buffer in new frame

Tags: frames

I use [tiling window manager](https://awesomewm.org/) and usually prefer it to handle emacs frames instead of using emacs windows. Is there a way I could force emacs to spawn new buffers in new frames automatically? Ideally this behavior should be toggled via some command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C-h v pop-up-frames` tells you this.  It should get you much of the way there.

> **`pop-up-frames`** is a variable defined in `window.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Original value was `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Whether `display-buffer' should make a separate frame.
>
> If `nil`, never make a separate frame.
>
> If the value is `graphic-only`, make a separate frame
>   on graphic displays only.
>
> Any other non-`nil` value means **always make a separate frame**.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

[This](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneOnOneEmacs), and its linked pages, might also help, at least by describing some of the problems of trying to use frames-only by default.

Answer (score 1):

[`pop-up-frames`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window-Options.html#Choosing-Window-Options) certainly does the trick but it is too awkward to use. It will spawn **everything** in new frame.

Much finer control may be reached by using [`display-buffer-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html#Choosing-Window). It allows conditionally opening buffers in new frames.

I wrote a small minor mode `pop-up-frames-mode` using `display-buffer-alist` method:

```lisp
;; https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511827/5745120
(defun which-active-modes ()
  "Which minor modes are enabled in the current buffer."
  (let ((active-modes))
    (mapc (lambda (mode) (condition-case nil
                        (if (and (symbolp mode) (symbol-value mode))
                            (add-to-list 'active-modes mode))
                      (error nil) ))
          minor-mode-list)
    active-modes))

(defun pop-up-frames-switch-to-buffer (buffer alist)
  "Pop up frames switch to buffer command."
  (member 'pop-up-frames-mode (which-active-modes)))

(setq display-buffer-alist
      (append display-buffer-alist
      '((pop-up-frames-switch-to-buffer . ((display-buffer-reuse-window display-buffer-pop-up-frame) . ((reusable-frames . 0)))
))))

(define-minor-mode pop-up-frames-mode
  "Pop up frames minor mode"
  :lighter " PUF")

(provide 'pop-up-frames-mode)
```

It spawns new frame only when `pop-up-frames-mode` is enabled in current buffer and does not create duplicate windows.