# Always open buffer in a new frame instead of a window

Tags: buffers, frames

I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54563/automatically-open-new-buffer-in-new-frame) question which suggested that setting pop-up-frames to a non-nil value should enable this behaviour. However when I added `(setq pop-up-frames t)` to my emacs init only some of the buffers was created in a new frame.

Opening files, org-agenda and org-capture does not open a new frame whereas mini-buffer complete, the command ran when press tab after M-x creates a new frame.

How can I make emacs always open buffers in new frames / GUI windows as opposed to splitting my current frame in half?

Thanks in advance for all help.

Olav

Comment: Could you care to explain how? As far as I can see they are not contradictory.  You might want to read this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame.

Comment: You know of `C-x 5 b` and `C-x 4 b`?